# wrapping image into a Picture Content Control in C# using OpenXML

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml-sdk

I have a problem. I need to insert an image into a picture content control, and the text wrapping parameter for the image should be set to 'In front of text.' However, I managed to set the text wrapping to 'In line with text.' Could you help me solve this issue using OpenXML?I don't know how to solve this kind of problem because I could only find old code fragments on the internet.

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
using A = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing;
using DW = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Wordprocessing;
using PIC = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Pictures;
using System.Drawing;

class Word
{
public static async Task Save(string filePath, string studentName, string date, string cause, string image)
{

    using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filePath, true))
    {
        MainDocumentPart mainPart = doc.MainDocumentPart;
        Body body = mainPart.Document.Body;
        string controlId = "pic";
        string[] content1 = {
        "...",
        "...",
        "...",
        $"{studentName}",
        "\n"
    };
        string[] content2 = { "...", "\n" };
        string[] content3 = { $"..." };
        string content4 = $".... {date}                                                             photo:";// Here should be a photo.


        foreach (string line in content1)
        {
            AddContentToDocument(body, line, JustificationValues.Right, "Times New Roman", 14);
        };
        foreach (string line in content2)
        {
            AddContentToDocument(body, line, JustificationValues.Center, "Times New Roman", 14);
        };
        foreach (string line in content3)
        {
            AddContentToDocument(body, line, JustificationValues.Both, "Times New Roman", 14);
        };

        //SdtElement contentControl = CreatePictureContentControl(doc, controlId);

        SdtElement contentControl = CreatePictureContentControl(doc, controlId);
        

        long newX = 50000L;
        long newY = 50000L;

        string imagePath = image;
        Image imageq = Image.FromFile(imagePath);
        byte[] imageBytes;
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            imageq.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            imageBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }



        InsertImageIntoContentControl(doc, filePath, controlId, imageBytes, mainPart, contentControl);
        AddContentToDocumentPCC(body, content4, JustificationValues.Left, "Times New Roman", 14, contentControl);
    }
}private static SdtBlock CreatePictureContentControl(WordprocessingDocument doc, string controlId)
{
    SdtBlock sdtBlock = new SdtBlock(
        new SdtProperties(
            new SdtAlias { Val = controlId },
            new SdtId { Val = -1 },
            new SdtContentPicture()
        ),
        new SdtContentBlock()
    );

    //doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Append(sdtBlock);

    return sdtBlock;
}

public static void InsertImageIntoContentControl(WordprocessingDocument doc, string filePath, string contentControlId, byte[] imageBytes, MainDocumentPart mainPart, SdtElement contentControl)
{
    if (contentControl != null)
    {
        AddImageToContentControl(mainPart, contentControl, imageBytes);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Content control {contentControlId} = null.");
    }
}

public static void AddImageToContentControl(MainDocumentPart mainPart, SdtElement contentControl, byte[] imageBytes)
{
    string imagePartId = "image001";
    ImagePart imagePart = mainPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Png, imagePartId);
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
    {
        ms.CopyTo(imagePart.GetStream());
    }
    Drawing drawing = new Drawing(
        new DW.Inline(
            new DW.Extent() { Cx = 990000L, Cy = 792000L },
            new DW.EffectExtent()
            {
                LeftEdge = 0L,
                TopEdge = 0L,
                RightEdge = 0L,
                BottomEdge = 0L
            },
            new DW.DocProperties() { Id = (UInt32Value)1U, Name = "Picture 1" },
            new DW.NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties(
                new A.GraphicFrameLocks() { NoChangeAspect = true })
            {

            },
            new A.Graphic(
                new A.GraphicData(
                    new PIC.Picture(
                        new PIC.NonVisualPictureProperties(
                            new PIC.NonVisualDrawingProperties() { Id = (UInt32Value)0U, Name = "New Bitmap Image.jpg" },
                            new PIC.NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties()),
                        new PIC.BlipFill(
                            new A.Blip() { Embed = imagePartId },
                            new A.Stretch(
                                new A.FillRectangle())),
                        new PIC.ShapeProperties(
                            new A.Transform2D(
                                new A.Offset() { X = 0L, Y = 0L },
                                new A.Extents() { Cx = 990000L, Cy = 792000L }),
                            new A.PresetGeometry(
                                new A.AdjustValueList()
                            )
                            { Preset = A.ShapeTypeValues.Rectangle })),
                new DW.WrapThrough()
                    )
                { Uri = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture" }),
            new DW.WrapNone(),
            new DW.Anchor(new DW.WrapNone())
        )
        {
            DistanceFromTop = (UInt32Value)0U,
            DistanceFromBottom = (UInt32Value)0U,
            DistanceFromLeft = (UInt32Value)0U,
            DistanceFromRight = (UInt32Value)0U,
            EditId = "50D07946"
        });
    contentControl.Descendants<Paragraph>().ToList().ForEach(p => p.Remove());
    contentControl.AppendChild(new Paragraph(new Run(drawing)));
}


static Paragraph AddContentToDocumentPCC(Body body, string text, JustificationValues justification, string fontName, int fontSize, SdtElement contentControl)
{//string + photo 
    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();

    ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties = new ParagraphProperties();
    Justification justificationElement = new Justification() { Val = justification };
    paragraphProperties.Append(justificationElement);

    RunProperties runProperties = new RunProperties();
    RunFonts runFonts = new RunFonts() { Ascii = fontName, HighAnsi = fontName };
    FontSize fontSizeElement = new FontSize() { Val = (fontSize * 2).ToString() };
    runProperties.Append(runFonts, fontSizeElement);

    Run run = new Run(runProperties, new Text(text));
    paragraph.Append(paragraphProperties, run, contentControl);

    body.Append(paragraph);
    return paragraph;
}

static Paragraph AddContentToDocument(Body body, string text, JustificationValues justification, string fontName, int fontSize)
{// string 
    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();


    ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties = new ParagraphProperties();
    Justification justificationElement = new Justification() { Val = justification };
    paragraphProperties.Append(justificationElement);

    RunProperties runProperties = new RunProperties();
    RunFonts runFonts = new RunFonts() { Ascii = fontName, HighAnsi = fontName };
    FontSize fontSizeElement = new FontSize() { Val = (fontSize * 2).ToString() };
    runProperties.Append(runFonts, fontSizeElement);


    Run run = new Run(runProperties, new Text(text));
    paragraph.Append(paragraphProperties, run);


    body.Append(paragraph);

    return paragraph;
}



public static async Task CreateFile(string student_name, string Date, string student_username, string Cause, string image)
{
    string file_name = $"{Date}.docx";
    string filePath1 = await CreateFolderAsync(student_name);
    string filePath = Path.Combine(filePath1, file_name);
    using (WordprocessingDocument wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Create(filePath, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
    {
        MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDocument.AddMainDocumentPart();
        mainPart.Document = new Document();
        Body body = mainPart.Document.AppendChild(new Body());
    }
    await Save(filePath, student_name, Date, Cause, image);
    await ApiGoogleDrive.UploadFileAsync(filePath, file_name, PostgreSQLDB.GetFromDBStudentsGoodleDiskFolder(student_username));
}

public static async Task<string> CreateFolderAsync(string student_name)
{
    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        string path = @"Word\";
        string path_student = Path.Combine(path, student_name + "\\");

        if (!Directory.Exists(path_student))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path_student);
        }

        return path_student;
    });
}
```

}

Comment: "I cannot attach the entire code for creating an image because it doesn't fit within the 220-character limit in the question" <- this is the limit for the *title* of the question, but you are encouraged to attach the code describing your problem in the *body* of your post, which apparently can be [as long as 30000 characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/176447/1182455). Please edit your question again and include the relevant code in the question itself.

Comment: Indeed, I have inserted the entire code.

Comment: According to the docs, [DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Wordprocessing.Inline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.drawing.wordprocessing.inline?view=openxml-2.8.1) supports only *inline* and *floating* states. Floating probably suits you better, but I'm not sure how to work with it.